# Does Pollard Rho not work for certain numbers?

Tags: algorithm, factorization

I'm trying to implement Pollard Rho based on pseudocode I found on Wikipedia, but it doesn't appear to work for the numbers 4, 8, and 25, and I have no clue why.

Here's my code:

```
    long long x = initXY;
    long long y = initXY;
    long long d = 1;

    while (d == 1) {
        x = polynomialModN(x, n);
        y = polynomialModN(polynomialModN(y, n), n);

        d = gcd(labs(x - y), n);
    }
    if (d == n)
        return getFactor(n, initXY + 1);

    return d;
```

This is my polynomial function:

```
long long polynomialModN(long long x, long long n) {
    return (x * x + 1) % n;
}
```

And this is example pseudocode from Wikipedia:

```
x ← 2; y ← 2; d ← 1
while d = 1:
    x ← g(x)
    y ← g(g(y))
    d ← gcd(|x - y|, n)
if d = n: 
    return failure
else:
    return d
```

Only difference: I don't return failure but instead try different initializing variables, as Wikipedia also notes this:

> Here x and y corresponds to x i {\displaystyle x_{i}} x_{i} and x j
>   {\displaystyle x_{j}} x_{j} in the section about core idea. Note that
>   this algorithm may fail to find a nontrivial factor even when n is
>   composite. In that case, the method can be tried again, using a
>   starting value other than 2 or a different g ( x ) {\displaystyle
>   g(x)} g(x).

Does Pollard-Rho just not work for certain numbers? What are their characteristics? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To see why it doesn't work, just print out the results of your polynomial function. When `n` is 4, the output always ends in the cycle `1,2,1,2,1,2`. When `n` is 8, the cycle is `2,5,2,5,2,5`, and when `n` is 25, the cycle is `1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5`. So you can see that those won't work unless you get lucky and find the answer before the cycle starts (which doesn't happen).

Comment: Alright, but why doesn't it work theoretically, and what other much larger numbers (if any) won't work?

Comment: To quote the Wikipedia entry, "So the sequence { x k mod p } {\displaystyle \{x_{k}{\bmod {p}}\}} {\displaystyle \{x_{k}{\bmod {p}}\}} will likely repeat much earlier than the sequence { x k } {\displaystyle \{x_{k}\}} {\displaystyle \{x_{k}\}}." Note the word likely. This is based on probabilities, assuming that the polynomial function acts like a random mapping mod the factors - this is not a guarantee. I would try a few different quadratics and perhaps a cubic or two and see if those work for the numbers not factored by the polynomial you have used so far.

Comment: Using https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-RHO i have not found a number for which it doesn't work.

Comment: It does not work for prime numbers (perhaps, you can limit number of steps and number of different functions to try, but, what limits to use?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pollard Rho does not work on even numbers. If you have an even number, first remove all factors of 2 before applying Pollard Rho to find the odd factors.

Pollard Rho properly factors 25, but it finds both factors of 5 at the same time, so it returns a factor of 25. That's correct, but not useful. So Pollard Rho will not find the factors of any power (square, cube, and so on).

Although I didn't run it, your Pollard Rho function looks okay. Wikipedia's advice to change the starting point might work, but generally doesn't. It is better, as Wikipedia also suggests, to change the random function *g*. The easiest way to do that is to increase the addend; instead of *x*²+1, use *x*²+*c*, where *c* is initially 1 and increases to 2, 3, … after each failure.

Comment: Actually, it may factor powers but only by pure luck.

Comment: Could you give me some background as to why that is? The function seems to work for most even numbers and works just fine for many squares as well (16, 36, 49, ...)

Comment: You are correct; the algorithm is probabilistic, so it sometimes factors even numbers and perfect powers. But it often fails on even numbers, so it is better to remove factors of 2 before calling Pollard Rho; in fact, you might want to also remove other small factors using trial division before calling Pollard Rho. The situation is similar with perfect powers; some factor, but most don't, so it is better to check for perfect powers before you start, or at least if you get a factor of _n_.

Comment: @user448810 Can you provide a reference to this claim "it often fails on even numbers and perfect powers"? I tried to search about it, but didn't find anything.

Comment: perhaps, it will not work with even numbers if Montgomery multiplication (with divisor which is a power of two) as that multiplication does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here, as x can be as big as n-1, the product in your polynomialModN function will overflow.